# Instalar la extención watermark en jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda

Estoy intentando instalar la extensión watermark para IPython. Lo intento con:

```
!conda install -y watermark
```

y me sale esto:

> ```
> Solving environment: failed
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
>   - watermark
>
> Current channels:
>
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-32
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-32
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-32
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-32
>   - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
> looking for, navigate to
>
>     https://anaconda.org
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

El paquete `watermark` está disponible desde el canal [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge):

```
conda install -y -c conda-forge watermark
```

O para añadir el canal de forma permanente:

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge 
conda install -y watermark
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo solucione con esto:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install watermark
```